# Non-virtual interface? (Need a very performant low level abstraction)

Tags: c++, architecture, abstraction, idioms, micro-optimization

I'm trying to micro-optimize my code at a very low level point in the application architecture. So here is my concrete scenario:

- I have a **parser class** which parses a graph file (nodes, edges, adjacency entries etc.)
- The file format is versioned, so there exist parsers for each version which are implemented as **separate classes** (ParserV1, ParserV2, ...).
- The parsers provide the same functionality to some upper layer in the application. Thus, they implement the same "**interface**".
- In C++, I'd implement such an interface as an abstract class with all functions being pure **virtual**.
- As virtual functions need another memory lookup and can't be bound statically at compile time and -- much more important -- will **not allow inlining** of small methods in the parser classes, using a classical sub-classing idiom wouldn't lead to the best performance I can achieve.

[Before describing my possible solutions, I want to explain why I'm doing micro-optimization here (you may skip this paragraph): The parser class has a lot of small methods, where "small" means that they don't do much. Most of them only read one or two bytes or even only one bit from a cached bit stream. So it should be possible to implement them in a very very efficient way, where a function call, when inlined, only needs a handful of machine commands.
 The methods are called very often in the application, since they look up node attributes in a very big graph (the world-wide road network), which might happen about one million times per user request, and such an request should be as fast as possible.]

Which is the way to go here? I can see the following methods to solve the problem:

1. Write an interface with pure virtual methods and subclass it. The performance will suffer.
2. Do not write such an interface. Each parser defines the same methods on its own. In the upper layer (which uses the parser) has pointers (as members) to each version subclass. In the beginning, instantiate the specific parser which should be used. Use a switch block and cast the parser instance to the explicit subclass whenever accessing a function. Will the performance better? (if/switch block vs. virtual table lookup).
3. Mix the two solutions 1. + 2.: Write an interface with pure virtual methods for seldom used methods, where performance isn't highly critical. If it is critical, don't provide a virtual method but use the second method.
4. Improving 2.: Provide non-virtual methods in the abstract class; keep a version number as a member variable in the abstract class (kind of own runtime type information) and implement the if/switch blocks and casts in these methods; then call the methods in the subclass. This provide both inlining and static binding.

Are there better ways to solve this problem? Is there any idiom for this?

To clarify, I have a lot of functions which are version-independent (at least until now), and are thus perfectly fitting in some super class. I will use a standard sub-classing design for most functions, while this questions only covers a solution for the version-dependent functions to be optimised. (Some of them aren't called very frequently and I can of course use virtual methods in these cases.) Besides this, I don't like the idea to make the parser class decide which methods need to be performant and which don't. (Although it would be possible to do so.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Thanks for this hint. Why didn't I think about it? Do you mean: `template<int V> class Parser{...}`, and then `Parser<1>` instead of `ParserV1`?

Comment: (JamesMcNellis wrote a comment which he deleted. He suggested to use a template class.)

Comment: Do you know about the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to optimize for the case where any public member function might be called at any time, but a small number of them are used much more than others?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes. But I don't like the idea to make the parser class decide which methods need to be performant and which don't. (Although it would be possible to do so.)

Comment: @Gigi I didn't know it before. I hope I understood the idea correctly: I then still have different classes, having the same implementation for some functions (statically linked / maybe inlined) but they can implement it differently (like an alternative to overwriting using virtual methods). But there is still the problem how the client should use such a class, because there is no AbstractParser of which the client could hold a pointer to and use; the pointer needs to be of a concrete type. What am I misunderstanding? (But thanks for this hint anyways, since I might combine multiple solutions.)

Comment: You are getting it right. It is a compromise: you renounce run-time dynamic binding for compile-time dynamic binding. Maybe if speed is absolutely essential you can "manually inline" all the code of the small functions... This mean maintaining spaghetti-functions, but parsers are all already like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, of couse, you should profile your code to figure-out how much are the vcalls performance-killing in your particular case (besides of potentially weaker optimizations).

Putting the optimization subject aside, I'm almost sure you won't get any significant performance gain by replacing virtual function call (or call a function by a pointer variable, which is almost the same) with a switch that calls compile-time-known functions in different cases.

If you **really** want a significant improvement - those are the most promising variants IMHO:

1. Try to redesign your interface to enable more complex functions. For instance, if you have a function that reads a single vertex - modify it to read (up to) N vertexes at once. And so on.
2. You may make your whole parsing code (that uses your parser) a `template` class/function, that will use a template parameter to instantiate the needed parser. Here you'll need neither interface nor virtual functions. At the very beginning (where you identify the version) - put a `switch`, for every recognized version call this function with the appropriate template parameter.

The latter will probably be superior from the performance point of view, OTOH this increases the code size

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of (2):

```
template <class Parser>
void MyApplication::HandleSomeRequest(Parser& p)
{
    int n = p.GetVertexCount();
    for (iVertex = 0; iVertex < n; iVertex++)
    {
        // ...    
        p.GetVertexEdges(iVertex, /* ... */);    
        // ...    
    }
}

void MyApplication::HandleSomeRequest(/* .. */)
{
    int iVersion = /* ... */;
    switch (iVersion)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            ParserV1 p(/* ... */);
            HandleSomeRequest(p);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        {
            ParserV2 p(/* ... */);
            HandleSomeRequest(p);
        }
        break;

    // ...
    }
}
```

The classes `ParserV1`, `ParserV2` and etc. do **not** have `virtual` functions. They also don't inherit any interface. They just implement some functions, such as `GetVertexCount`.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. In point 2., do you mean an integer template argument? Or a concrete implementation class, like the user "templatetypedef" suggested in his answer?

Comment: @leemes: The template parameter is a `class`. I.e. - the concrete class of the parser that should be used do parse the data. @templatetypedef's proposal is somewhat overcomplicated IMHO, since it still uses `virtual` functions, which kills the whole idea.

Comment: Ok. But I still see the following problem in your second solution: In the very beginning, when I recognize the version (of course at run-time), I instanciate the concrete parser implementation. So far, so good. But the member in the client, where to store this instance, has to be of a concrete type, too, doesn't it? So I need a somewhat untyped pointer and switch over the versions *every time* I use the parser instantiation. Did I misunderstand your idea?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood your idea. You are talking about making the *client class* a template class, which template argument depends on the version. Nice idea, yes. So in the end, this minimises the number of virtual (and non-inlined) functions whenever the client performs a lot of calls to the parser in one single call from the client's client to the client. (In fact, I have more layers in my architecture above the parser.)

Answer (score 3):

One option that might work well is the following: have each parser class define methods with the same signatures, but does so completely independently of each other class.  Then, introduce a secondary class hierarchy that implements all of these same functions virtually, then forwards each method call to a concrete parser object.  That way, the implementation of the parser gets all the benefits of inlining, since from the perspective of the class all calls can be resolved statically, while the client gets the benefits of polymorphism, since any method call will dynamically resolve to the proper type.

The catch in doing this is that you use extra memory (the wrapper object takes up space), and you will also probably have at least one extra indirection involved when you call the parser functions, since the call goes

> client → wrapper → implementation

Depending on how infrequently you call the methods from the client, this implementation might work very well.

Using templates, it's possible to implement the wrapper layer *extremely* succinctly.  The idea is the following.  Suppose that you have methods fA, fB, and fC.  Start off by defining a base class like this:

```
class WrapperBase {
public:
    virtual ~WrapperBase() = 0;

    virtual void fA() = 0;
    virtual void fB() = 0;
    virtual void fC() = 0;
};
```

Now, define the following template type as a subclass:

```
template <typename Implementation>
    class WrapperDerived: public WrapperBase {
private:
    Implementation impl;

public:
    virtual void fA() {
        impl.fA();
    }
    virtual void fB() {
        impl.fB();
    }
    virtual void fC() {
        impl.fC();
    }
};
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
WrapperBase* wrapper = new WrapperDerived<MyFirstImplementation>();
wrapper->fA();
delete wrapper;

wrapper = new WrapperDerived<MySecondImplementation>();
wrapper->fB();
delete wrapper;
```

In other words, all of the wrapper code can be generated for you by the compiler by just instantiating the `WrapperDerived` template.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see the advantage over directly using virtual methods in the parser class, since both solutions need virtual calls from the client to the final implementations. Only at another point in time / code. Will it be possible to merge your idea with my method 4., where often used methods use my solution and seldom used methods use your solution?

Comment: @leemes- The advantage is that all of the calls within the parser class to itself can be inlined, meaning that the implementation can be maximally inlined.  You still have the virtual calls from the client, but the implementation ends up being a lot faster.  Am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid virtual calls at all. I see one possible alternative in switching over the different versions I implemented (I know, bad code style...), and casting the implementation instance to the specific class; then call the method which can be (can it?) inlined. Like this: `if (version == 2) ((ParserV2*)parser)->func(); else if ...`

Comment: @leemes: `if` blocks will be _far slower_ than `virtual` functions.  If you need to hold a pointer to an unknown implementation, you cannot avoid any more `virtual` functions over what templatetypedef said.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ok I used the wrong words: I'm trying to avoid "non-inlineability" at all. Methods having only one statement (which needs for example, let's say, about 3 to 5 machine commands), are perfectly suited for inlining, but this isn't possible when it's virtual. (So I wrongly used the word virtual for this optimisation.)

Comment: @leemes: by far, the bestway to avoid non-inlineability is to not use virtual functions, but in most cases to do so would be absurd, and make the program go slow.  You don't want your program to be slow do you?  Use virtual functions instead.